# deleting a user with query builder laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete a user account using laravel [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#deletes) so I'm doing this

AuthRepository

```
class AuthRepository implements IAuthRepository
{
    ....

    public function delete($user_id) 
    {
        $res = User::where('id', $user_id->id)->delete();;

        if ($res) {
            return response('Success, user was deleted', 204);
        } else {
            return response()->json(error);
        }
    }

}
```

In controller

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $auth;

    public function delete($user_id)
    {
        return $user_id->delete();
    }

}
```

in api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
        // Delete user
        Route::post('user/delete/{user_id}', 'AuthController@delete');
    });

});
```

Passing `user_id` to `${API_URL}/auth/user/delete/{user_id}` I'm facing

`Call to a member function delete()` in Controller on line `return $user_id->delete();`. Can someone please explain me why is this happening, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the route model binding and to this instead:

```
public function delete(User $user)
{
   return $user->delete();
}
```

And your route:

```
Route::post('user/delete/{user}', 'AuthController@delete');
```

You cannot call `delete()` on an `integer`.

Comment: It will map the id to a user, behind the scenes Laravel will inject this: `User::findOrFail($user);` and give you an instance of a model, instead of integer. As you are trying this instead `1->delete()` which throws an exception: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I'm a bit confused on how is laravel doing this

Comment: @copser there is a middleware that does this, `SubstituteBindings`. This answer is using "Implicit Route Model Binding"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Route model binding as suggested by @nakov and insist on using `id` then you have to get the user first before deleting.

```
public function delete($user_id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    return $user->delete();
}
```